# statistical test for analyzing survey data

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, group-differences

One question of my survey (n=468) was to indicate on a scale from 1 to 5 how well they know our government. My hypothesis is that women know our government better than men. What statistical test do I have to use to measure this?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be translating your hypothesis "that women know our government better than men" into statistical language. The usual translation is that the mean of answers from women is higher than the mean of answers from men. To see if this difference is significant the most usual way is an one sided two sample [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) that can be dealt with by any statistical package.

If you wanted to tell apart to tell effects from different causes on your answers (e.g. sex, level of income, level of studies, age and so) then you could use more complex tools like multiple regression or ANOVA.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that as the dependent variable in this study (knowledge of government) is on an ordinal scale a t-test may not be appropriate, and alternative, possibly non-parametric, statistics should be considered.

Comment: @Ian_Fin could you make an example of such statistics?

Comment: @amarchin The Mann-Whitney U Test would be the non-parametric alternative to the t-test